# python-fastcgi extension

Tags: python, fastcgi

There's not much documentation surrounding the [python-fastcgi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-fastcgi) C library, so I'm wondering if someone could provide a simple example on how to make a simple FastCGI server with it. A "Hello World" example would be great.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I misread the question. Ooops.

[Jon's Python modules](http://jonpy.sourceforge.net/) is a collection of useful modules and includes a great FastCGI module: http://jonpy.sourceforge.net/fcgi.html

Here's the example from the page:

```
import jon.cgi as cgi 
import jon.fcgi as fcgi

class Handler(cgi.Handler):
  def process(self, req):
    req.set_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    req.write("Hello, world!\n")

fcgi.Server({fcgi.FCGI_RESPONDER: Handler}).run()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a fastcgi WSGI wrapper such as [this one](http://svn.saddi.com/py-lib/trunk/fcgi.py), so you aren't tied in to the fastcgi approach from the start.

And then a simple test.fgi file like such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from fcgi import WSGIServer

def app(env, start):

    start('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield 'Hello, World!\n'
    yield '\n'

    yield 'Your environment is:\n'
    for k, v in sorted(env.items()):
        yield '\t%s: %r\n' % (k, v)

WSGIServer(app).run()
```